# (Beginner Java): Constructor no arguments?

Tags: java, constructor, arguments

I am trying to make a simple program that takes the average of three number, but I get an error saying that says

"constructor average in class average cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: int,int,int "

Here is my code:

```
public class ave {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
average object = new average(3,4,6);
 }
}
```

and here is my constructor code

```
public class average {
public double takeaverage(double first, double second, double third) {
 double ave = (first + second + third)/3;
 System.out.println(ave);
 return ave; } 
}
```

Comment: `object.takeaverage(3,4,6);` it's a method

Comment: Make sure you're using Pascal-casing for your class names (i.e. Average, AverageClass, ThisIsAReallyLongNameForAClassThatAveragesThreeNumbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor's name should be same as the class name and feature no return type.
Try the following:

```
public class ave {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
Average object = new Average(3,4,6);
 }
}


public class Average {
    public Average(double first, double second, double third){
        double ave = (first + second + third)/3;
        System.out.println(ave);
    } 
}
```

and if you don't want to change the code of Class `Average`, then just call the method from that class as following:

```
public class ave {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
Average object = new Average();
 double Avg = object.takeaverage(3,4,6);
 }
}


public class Average {
public double takeaverage(double first, double second, double third) {
 double ave = (first + second + third)/3;
 System.out.println(ave);
 return ave; } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The constructor must have the same name as the class.

You have to create:

```
public average(double a, double b, double c)
```

Actually the only constructor existing in the class is the constructor without arguments, that is created automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined a constructor method that receives these arguments (3, 4, 6).
You have to create a constructor method like this:

```
public class average {
public double result

public average(int a, int b, int c){
this.result=this.takeaverage(double(a),double(b),double(c))
}
public double takeaverage(double first, double second, double third) {
 double ave = (first + second + third)/3;
 System.out.println(ave);
 return ave; } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to take the average of 3 numbers, you can do it without creating an average object. I have shown it below:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Ave {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double number1, number2, number3;
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number 1:");
        number1 = console.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter number 2:");      
        number2 = console.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter number 3:");
        number3 = console.nextDouble();
        double average = (number1 + number2 + number3)/3;
        System.out.println("The average is: " + average);
    }
}
```

The above program asks the user for 3 numbers and prints out their average. Note that it is still a bit redundant. You can also modify it to ask for average of any numbers, like shown below:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Ave {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int howMany;
        double sum = 0.0;
        double number, average;
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to take average of:");
        howMany = console.nextInt();
        int count = 1;
        while(count <= howMany){
            System.out.println("Enter number " + count);
            number = console.nextDouble();
            sum += number;
            count++;
        }
        average = sum/howMany;
        System.out.println("The average is: " + average);
    }
}
```

You can modify the programs to take the average of 3 numbers without asking the user too, where the doubles number1, number2, and number3 will be given numbers (hard-coded, which is not a good practice in general).

Answer (score 0):

You have created the "takeaverage" method but haven't invoked it. And maybe you should use a setter or pass the three numbers using the constructor and initialize and then only call the "takeaverage" method for a double value and get the average assigned to that double variable.

You need to use the default constructor and create the object from "average" class. Below is a very simple solution :

```
public class average {
     public double takeaverage(double first, double second, double third) {
         double ave = (first + second + third)/3;
         System.out.println(ave);
         return ave; 
     } 
} 




 //main class
    public class ave{
      public static void main(String []args){
            average object = new average();
            object.takeaverage(3,4,6);
         }

    }
```